# Is "vector" countable?

Tags: countable-nouns

I was wondering if "vector" is countable or not. I've been using it in plural form (vectors) but I don't know if that is correct.

Comment: Certainly one can have multiple vectors (in the mathematical/engineering sense) -- 2, 3, 538.  And I'm not offhand thinking of a context where "vector" would mean an uncountable mass (that wasn't infinite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, vector is countable, and the plural form is indeed vectors as mentioned in the [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/vector):

> **vector** /ˈvɛktɚ/ *noun*
>
> *plural* **vectors**
>
> [count]
>
> **1** *mathematics* **:** a quantity (such as velocity) that has size and direction
>
> (...)

If you [search for "vectors" on Google Scolar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=vectors) you will also find hundreds of thousands of scientific publications using the plural form, so I would say it is definitely accepted to say vectors.

Comment: That's not how you find a definitive answer. Consult a good dictionary instead.

Comment: @Kris The plural form was not mentioned in the dictionaries I consulted before thinking of going to Google Scolar to prove my point. But you are right. I found a dictionary I can use now, so I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I majored in Applied Math in college, so I think I'm more of an authority on if "vectors" than a dictionary compiled by English major types. "Vectors" is indeed cromulent.

Comment: Great! Your vote is back. :)

Comment: Kris, when you're seeing hundreds thousands of mentions of "vectors" in its natural habitat, why on earth would you what to consult a dictionary??? Where do you think dictionaries get their definitions from, original documents or from thin air?

Comment: @AndyBlankertz Applied Math major here too. "Countable" has a specific meaning here, although I'm not personally a fan. I like singular and plural better. It is kind of a silly question to begin with. Asking about countability makes more sense for, say, "people" or "data" or "javelina" where there is some ambiguity in usage. Next: Is scalar countable? Ugh, yes....

Comment: My bad- I thought it was asking about plurals.

Comment: @AndyBlankertz No problem! The more math, the better, even here, IMNSHO.

Answer (score 3):

To tell weather or not a noun is countable, you refer to a dictionary.

Here's what [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/vector) says:

> **vec‧tor** `[countable]` technical
>
> 1. a quantity such as force that has a direction as well as size
> 2. an insect or animal that passes disease from one person to another [= carrier]:
>      *Mosquitoes are feared as vectors of malaria.*
> 3. in biology, an animal or human cell that is used to carry DNA from one cell to another to produce a   clone